# How do I find the line number for Visualforce errors in Eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse

Most Visualforce errors in Eclipse are erroneously located in **Line 0**. Pasting the same code in the Salesforce via a web browser exposes the line number of the error. How do I find the line number for Visualforce errors in Eclipse?

### Eclipse:

[image]

### Salesforce via a web browser:

[image]

Comment: I must admit I rarely use Eclipse and stick to the web interface for VF and code.  It'll be a year or more before the Eclipse tooling is improved as its depending on the Tooling API being finished off.

Comment: @StevenHerod, thank you for your input about the Tooling API being incomplete. However, I would like to give a personal opinion that Eclipse should be used for best practices mainly because of the **Local History** feature, and also for the ability to notify if you are trying to save a file which had been modified by someone else while you were editing.

Comment: If it doesn't work, its not a 'best practice'.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly, but workable solution is successive commenting out with `<!-- -->`. I find myself entering only a few lines of VF markup at a time and then doing Save so any error reported on line 0 will be in the last few lines entered.  Sort of a 1970's approach to diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this isn't supported by the metadata API which is what Eclipse uses, whereas the in-org editor and developer console leverage the new tooling API.

The only way to find the error is to search manually, though as long as you're saving frequently you'll know it's likely to be in one of the elements you last added to the page so finding it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Sublime Text Editor and installed MavensMate Plugin . It works like a charm for Salesforce and its really fast. It uses the latest Tooling API (beta).I

Here are the links:

http://www.sublimetext.com/2
https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/tree/2.0